# Is there way to pass Symfony variables to translation without keys

Tags: php, symfony, translation

we are now using custom translations for our project in PHP and I want to migrate them to Symfony ones. Everything looks great, but my only concern is that variable placeholders needs key to bind successfully, can I somehow change the code to accept translation variables in sequence (without keys)?

**Let me show an example:**
Our code now:

```
$translator->translate('For the period %date%, %data%', [$dateInterval, $additionalData]);
```

But this is how Symfony wants it:

```
return $this->symfonyTranslator->trans('For the period %date%, %data%', ['%date%' => $dateInterval, '%data%' => $additionalData]);
```

This is what I want:

```
return $this->symfonyTranslator->trans('For the period %date%, %data%', [$dateInterval, $additionalData]);
```

Is this somehow possible? I didn't find it anywhere in the documentation and Google didn't help either.

Comment: If you managed to find a solution, please post it as answer (you are allowed to answer your own questions) and accept it, don't edit it into the question. That way, your question can be filtered as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by myself this is the code (in case anyone needs it):

Basically, it gets all %variables% and sets them as array keys with corresponding array values from $parameters variable.

```
public function translate(string $gettextString, array $parameters = []): string
{
    $gettextString = $this->newlinesNormalizer->normalize($gettextString);

    preg_match_all('~\%(\S+)\%~m', $gettextString, $matches);

    $variables = $matches[array_key_last($matches)];

    $finalParameters = [];
    foreach ($variables as $index => $variable) {
        if (substr($variable, 0, 1) === '%' && substr($variable, -1) === '%') {
            continue;
        }

        $finalParameters['%' . $variable . '%'] = $parameters[$index];
    }

    return $this->symfonyTranslator->trans($gettextString, $finalParameters);
}
```